# How to use generics to specify super-class relationships with Comparable type

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I created a method getMax that takes and array of Comparable as a parameter and compares the elements to find the max element, but I also have to implement generics to specify super-class relationships and I do not really understand how I would do that. Below is the src for my non-generic method

```
public static Comparable getMax(Comparable [] array){
    Comparable max=array[0];
    for(int x=0; x<array.length;x++){
        if(array[x].compareTo(max)==1)
            max=array[x];
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your `getMax` method with generics like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T getMax(T[] array){
    T max=array[0];
    for(int x=0; x<array.length;x++){
        if(array[x].compareTo(max)==1)
            max=array[x];
    }
    return max;
}
```

(You see, the trick is replacing `Comparable` by  `T`,
and declaring `T` to be `Comparable<T>`.)

Then, for example you can use it like this:

```
String[] strings = { "Bob", "Alice", "Charlie" };
String maxString = getMax(strings);  // gives "Charlie"
```

Comment: or even better, `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`